# Is there a way for me to see all of the words I have learned for each race?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I have learned at least 20 words at this point but I have no idea what they are unless I talk to that race of people. Is there an in-game dictionary that I can see what I know (and what words I have seen but don't know)?

Comment: I started a second file to show my friend the game and it appears that you learn every language in the same order every time. (Which is a little disappointing but oh well) so hopefully people compile a list of the order and if you know what word you learned last you can see what words you know and what you don't.

Comment: Just as a bit of advice, someone completed their knowledge of the Korvax language recently and although they didn't keep a detailed count, they estimated it to be around 400 words. So if that's the same for all races then you're looking at potentially 1200+ words, although the Atlas dictionary may have less in it due to how infrequently you encounter the Atlas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. The most you can check is how many you've discovered by looking at your journey tab.

I'm guessing this way you can't you can't just look at which words are missing and try to decipher the language yourself.

Comment: I could have sworn they wanted us to do that honestly. That is super disappointing.

Comment: I did read somewhere that the translation is consistent, so if, for example, you were to record the dozen or so lines of untranslated speech from one particular alien, learn a significant portion of the language, then record the partially-translated dialogue and match up the untranslated words, and repeat as you continue learning the language, eventually switching to matching up the translated words, you could create a full translation guide, which another player would be able to use.